# How can perform conditional locking on insert/select Sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, concurrency, locking

Table `Meta_Cache` (`[Value] NVARCHAR(MAX)`, `[UserID] NVARCHAR`)

I have a stored procedure that inserts 5 rows for each user.

Each user can have multiple concurrent call, first call from specific `UserID` inserts a set of values and other call just read the values for that `UserID`. This doesn't work by checking

```
if exists(Select 1 from Meta_cache Where UserID = @UserID)
```

when there is multiple concurrent calls.

I want to specific locking mechanism that locks conditionally on rows for specific `UserID` and another User Don't get affected by locking.

I just refers some script from

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

row locking can always lead to page lock and table lock

```
UPDATE
Employee WITH (ROWLOCK)
SET FullName='John Does'
WHERE Department = 'IT'
```

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/control-sql-server-locking-with-hints/

you can always avoid race condition by encapsulating your queries in a SQL Transaction.